# What is the biggest known jigsaw puzzle size by pieces as of 2018?

Tags: jigsaw-puzzle

Biggest I've observed so far are 18000 pieces, right?

Comment: Not sure that this is the right place for this question...

Comment: Go to Amazon and you will easily find several 32000 piece jigsaw puzzles and even a [33,600 piece](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00IA3HH5K) one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the creation and/or solving of puzzles.

Comment: I agree. Flagging with you.

Comment: I think this is on topic, but I don’t think it’s a good question (the answer is easy to research on your own)

Answer (score 4):

> According to the Guinness Book of World Records [This Puzzle](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-jigsaw-puzzle-most-pieces) Is the largest currently. This jigsaw puzzle has 551,232 pieces in total and is located in Vietnam.

Comment: also i have been sniped

Answer (score 4):

[551232 pieces](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-jigsaw-puzzle-most-pieces) though I am not sure that this question belongs here...